False negative rates of KS and AD tests are absurdly high
I am running simulations in R where I want to measure the relative false negative rates of the Kolmogorov–Smirnov (KS) test and the Anderson Darling (AD) test. I'm not sure if I'm using the terminology correctly here, but what I mean by false negative is that the test yields a significant result ($p < \alpha$) even when the sample data is drawn from the assumed distribution of the test. I thought that the false negative rate would be approximately equal to $\alpha$, however instead I am getting results at or near 1. For example, here I draw 50 samples from a lognormal distribution, and then perform each goodness of fit test, counting the number of times the test gives a significant result:
  library(DescTools)

  alpha = 0.05
  sims = 100
  sampleSize = 50
  fnAD = 0
  fnKS = 0

  for(i in 1:sims){
    
    data = rlnorm(sampleSize, 2, 3)
    test = AndersonDarlingTest(data, "plnorm")
    if(test$p.value < alpha){
      fnAD = fnAD + 1
    }
    
    test = ks.test(data, "plnorm")
    if(test$p.value < alpha){
      fnKS = fnKS + 1
    }
    
  }

  print(c(fnAD/sims, fnKS/sims)) 


I find that this happens regardless of the parameters I use to define the lognormal distribution and it happens at different sample sizes. Why is the false negative rate so high? Is there a mistake in my code, or am I fundamentally misunderstanding something about goodness of fit tests?

While Dave has dealt with the central issue here, I would add that goodness of fit tests are generally biased (have power below $\alpha$) against some alternatives at least in non-large samples. This boas might be expected when classes of alternative are very broad.

@Glen_b That's really interesting! Do you have a reference?

No reference offhand, but does this help? It has a bunch of examples - https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/541594/805

The test functions seem to use default parameter settings unless you specify them, which you do not. In the case of the log-normal, the default parameters corresponding to plnorm and 0 and 1, rather than the  2 and 3, respectively, used in the data simulation line: data = rlnorm(sampleSize, 2, 3).
Therefore, you are testing a null hypothesis of $H_0: \vec\theta = (0, 1)$ when the reality is that $\vec\theta = (2, 3)$. I would hope a test could catch that! Thus, what you have seen is that $50$ is a large enough sample size for each of these tests to be quite powerful, at the $\alpha = 0.05$-level, at detecting such a difference.
If you simulate with rlnorm(sampleSize, 0, 1), you should get more reasonable false "negative" rates (though most people would refer to this as a false positive). Likewise, you will get more reasonable rates if you specify the 2, 3 parameters in the test, such as below.
library(DescTools)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2024)
sims <- 1000
sampleSize <- 50

p_KS <- p_AD <- rep(NA, sims)

for(i in 1:sims){
  
  data <- rlnorm(sampleSize, 2, 3)
  test <- DescTools::AndersonDarlingTest(data, "plnorm", 2, 3)
  p_AD[i] <- test$p.value
  
  test <- ks.test(data, "plnorm", 2, 3)
  p_KS[i] <- test$p.value
  
}

d_KS <- data.frame(
  pval = p_KS,
  ECDF = ecdf(p_KS)(p_KS),
  Test = "Kolmogorov-Smirnov"
)
d_AD <- data.frame(
  pval = p_AD,
  ECDF = ecdf(p_AD)(p_AD),
  Test = "Anderson-Darling"
)
d <- rbind(d_KS, d_AD)
ggplot(d, aes(x = pval, y = ECDF, col = Test)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("p-value") +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

As is hoped when the null hypothesis is true, the p-values for each test are (roughly) $U(0, 1)$-distributed.


As a side note, it is useful to set a seed at the beginning of this kind of Monte Carlo simulation so that others can exactly replicate your results (or that you can replicate your own results a year later when the reviewers get back to you).
